# user data on facebook fan page app

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-apps

I have created a application and connected it to a fan page so that application content is loaded in that page.

To access user_id and name of user can only be accessed if user have authorized the application.

**How application can be authorized at the same time as user have liked the page?**

I mean that when user clicks on like page button application authorization dialog box should also appear. Or if i am wrong please suggest the right way.

**--- EDIT ----**

I am using php-sdk v3.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible, the page like button is not connected in any way to your application.

What you can do is parse the signed_request parameter which is passed to your application to check if the user has liked the page, if he did you can then check if you can get the user object and redirect him to authorization if needed.

If you don't need the user id or any other extended features (such as posting to the wall) and just want to check if a user has liked the page you can just use the signed request and forget about the rest of the authorization.

You can decode the signed_request using your application secret key and the following function:

```
function parse_signed_request_outside($signed_request, $secret) {
    list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);

    // decode the data
    $sig = base64_url_decode_outside($encoded_sig);
    $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode_outside($payload), true);

    if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
        error_log('Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256');
        return null;
    }

    // check sig
    $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
    if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
        error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
        return null;
    }

    return $data;
}

function base64_url_decode_outside($input) {
    return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
}
```

In order to determine the like you need to do the following:

```
$secret = "SECRET KEY";

$decodedSignedRequest = parse_signed_request_outside($_REQUEST['signed_request'], $secret);

if ($decodedSignedRequest['page']['liked'] == 1){
{
   // load content
}
```